# Please I wish to auto fill the radio button when I click on the table rows

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, radio-button

When I click on a row on the table, all the data enters the text fields in relation to each column but the radio button does not select (e.g male or female) and I want the radio button to select either male or female button when I click on the rows. I know that for filling the text fields, it is

jTextField_Matricule.set text(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).to string());

And I wish to know the code to do the same for radio buttons

Comment: ` private void TableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)Table.getModel();
        int selectedRowIndex = Table.getSelectedRow();
        
        jTextField_Matricule.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
        jTextField_StudentName.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
       
        jTextField_DateOfBirth.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 3).toString());
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

Assumptions
1. Column index of "Gender" column is 4.
2. Gender is stored as a `String` in the table.

```
if (model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 4).toString().equals("Male")) {
  jRadioButtonMale.setSelected(true);
}
else if (model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 4).toString().equals("Female")) {
  jRadioButtonFemale.setSelected(true);
}
```

(If you show your code, we would be able to provide a more precise answer.)